# Write rows to SQL server

Tags: jdbc, azure-sql-database, databricks

I have a table in SQL server. I am trying to append a spark dataframe from databricks to the SQL table. I am able to append the new rows but the problem is that it appends randomly to the SQL table. I want to append the new rows to the end of the SQL table. How do I do that?

SQL table

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║   Name      a   b   c   d   ║
╠═════════════════════════════╣
║1  Lisa      5   4   1   3   ║
║2  Timmy     3   2   7   2   ║  
║3  Rann      2   3   1   5   ║
║4  Bob       1   6   3   4   ║
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

Spark dataframe

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║   Name      a   b   c   d   ║
╠═════════════════════════════╣
║1  Mark      10  3   2   4   ║
║2  Rudy      5   6   7   8   ║  
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

What I want

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║   Name      a   b   c   d   ║
╠═════════════════════════════╣
║1  Lisa      5   4   1   3   ║
║2  Timmy     3   2   7   2   ║  
║3  Rann      2   3   1   5   ║
║4  Bob       1   6   3   4   ║
║5  Mark      10  3   2   4   ║
║6  Rudy      5   6   7   8   ║
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

When I append using this code

```
df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url=jdbcurl, table="employee")
```

I get this result in the SQL server. **Mark** and **Rudy** should be at the bottom but it appends randomly. Is there a parameter that I am suppose to add?

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║   Name      a   b   c   d   ║
╠═════════════════════════════╣
║1  Lisa      5   4   1   3   ║
║2  Rudy      5   6   7   8   ║
║3  Timmy     3   2   7   2   ║
║4  Mark      10  3   2   4   ║
║5  Rann      2   3   1   5   ║
║6  Bob       1   6   3   4   ║
╚═════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: You can have a column within your dataframe that is integer and represent a primary key in sql table then you can see it in order when you do select. This is just a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables in SQL are not ordered.  It's a set.  Put in other words, you can feel free to believe they are being added at the end, but there's no guarantee that they will come back out in any order based on insertion order.

If you want to get data out in a specific order, you should run a query with an ORDER BY on it it based on the order you wish to see them.  That could be a column represented the time of insertion if you'd like.